# Sublime Text 2 and Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, sublimetext2

So I'm trying to make it so that I can start Sublime Text 2 from the terminal through this command, given by the Sublime Text documentation:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

But for some reason this is not working. I get this error from my terminal:

```
ln: /Users/connorblack/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Other details: I have SB2 in my Applications folder. I'm trying to do RoR development.

Comment: Why not using an alias ? alias subl='/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have a ~/bin directory, just do

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

And then retry the command, it should work

Note that to use subl from this folder you will still need to add it to your `PATH`, add this line to your .bashrc or .zshrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/connorblack/bin
```

Comment: I have the alias in my bin but for some reason trying `subl` into the terminal still won't open SB2

Comment: yeah you need to update your PATH, you can run the export line directly in bash and retry running `subl`, it will work. In order to do this for every bash session, you have to put the line in either .profile or .bashrc

Comment: I added it to .bashrc

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/connorblack/bin

Comment: ok now that its in the bashrc file, just start a new bash session (new tab in terminal, or reopen the current one should do it) and the command will work

Comment: I've been trying. Still getting this: Connors-MacBook-Pro:~ connorblack$ subl
-bash: subl: command not found

Comment: what is the output of echo $PATH

Comment: /Users/connorblack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin:/Users/connorblack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin:/Users/connorblack/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin:/Users/connorblack/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19039/discussion-between-yfrancis-and-connor-black)