# Subl shortcut not found in command line

Tags: macos, bash, sublimetext2

Trying to get Sublime Text 2 to work on my command line (Mac OS X) using the "subl" command.

Followed these simple instructions: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html

When I do `$ subl ~/.bashrc` I get this error: `-bash: subl: command not found`. However, if I use the full path or even `$ ~/bin/subl ~/.bashrc`, the file will successfully open in Sublime.

What could cause the shortcut "subl" to not be found? Do I need to set this somewhere (bashrc, bash_profile, etc)?

Comment: Quote from the link you posted "The first task is to make a symlink to subl. Assuming you've placed Sublime Text 2 in the Applications folder, **and that you have a ~/bin directory in your path**". You should read and understand what environment variables are and how they are used. It'll be very useful in general. zplesivcak's answer is correct.

Comment: You've been around SO long enough to (hopefully) know that you should search before asking a question. Check out all the questions over there **`-->`** in the "Related" section and see if perhaps you could have solved this yourself...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 and Terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217243/sublime-text-2-and-terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `~/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable, bash should be able to find `subl`:

```
export PATH=~/bin:${PATH}
```

Add this line to your `.bashrc` if you want `subl` available in every new `bash` session.

Answer (score 2):

That's because ~/bin is not set in your PATH. You can set it by adding one line to your .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```